# Python to sharepoint Forbidden for URL

Tags: python, sharepoint, sharepoint-list

I was looking to connect to my corporate sharepoint list but for testing purposes i am using this dummy templatei created.

```
from shareplum import Site
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth

cred = HttpNtlmAuth('email I use to login', 'password')


site = Site('https://griffithcollege628.sharepoint.com/sites/Sharepointtest/', auth=cred)
sp_list = site.List('list name')

list_data = sp_list.GetListItems()
```

But when i get to this line:

```
site = Site('https://griffithcollege628.sharepoint.com/sites/Sharepointtest/', auth=cred)
```

I get the following error:

```
Shareplum HTTP Post Failed : 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://griffithcollege628.sharepoint.com/sites/Sharepointtest//_vti_bin/lists.asmx
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried with the below method and I am able to get the list items.
Let me know if it is working.

```
from shareplum import Office365, Site
from shareplum.site import Version

server_url = "https://my_page.sharepoint.com/"
site_url = server_url + "sites/my_site_name"
authcookie = Office365(server_url, username=Username,password=Password).GetCookies() #here username is my mail ID
site = Site(site_url, version=Version.v365, authcookie=authcookie)
sp_list = site.List('my_list_name')
sp_data = sp_list.GetListItems()
```

Comment: Hello! thank you for giving me a hand out with this, much appreciated. I wanted to point out that i am using Sharepoint on-premise and maybe the Office365 wont work there? but il go ahead and give it a try! thank you so much, il get you a response immediately

Comment: One more thing to consider is if your SharePoint list has more than 5000 items(rows) then you will get the same error. So make sure your SharePoint site has less than 5000 list items. This is kind of a drawback with SharePoint list

Answer (score 1):

There should only be one `/` before the `_vti_bin`. Try removing the trailing `/` from your site variable.

I don't do python, so I don't know if that authentication thing works, but I know SharePoint enough to see that the URL with the double `//` is invalid.

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.

Comment: Hey ! so i removed the last back slash but still get the forbidden URL error: Exception has occurred: ShareplumRequestError
Shareplum HTTP Post Failed : 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://griffithcollege628.sharepoint.com/sites/Sharepointtest/_vti_bin/lists.asmx

Comment: Maybe it's time to contact SharePlum support. Does the script auth even work? Does Sharepoint even allow this kind of authentication?

Answer (score 1):

Please check if the user ID you are using to connect is added to the SharePoint Site.

Comment: I tried everything, but I think its because im connecting to a on-premise sharepoint

Comment: Any way i could reach you somehow to help me on this . you seem well of experienced maybe you could advise me at a cost, as im desperate

Comment: @King That URL does not look like an on-premises SharePoint. That's a SharePoint online URL. Can you get to the URL in the browser??

Comment: Hello!!!! So could you see based on a screen shot i just added to the question? This is the link: share.amazon.com/sites/IPV

Comment: Im really sorry for the late reply